# Reached second execution of fulfillment lambda on the same utterance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Using AWS Lex and Lambda, I am trying to build a lambda function which,
first validates the invoked intent and,
then moves forward with the questions (to assign values to slots).

Towards the end of fulfimentCodeHook, an error occurs, 
**"Reached second execution of fulfillment lambda on the same utterance"**

Comment: I am also getting the same error

Comment: Are you trying to validate an intent on its invocation?

Comment: I have created two intents(with different utterances) within the same bot. In my lambda code I check the incoming intent_name and based on that I call different functions. I do not get error when I test the lambda function from lambda function console but when I execute this from Lex console I get the above error. I also tried to create two separate lambda functions based on two intents(within same bot) but still I get same error

Comment: Ok. Are you using dialogAction's type as 'confirmIntent' anywhere?

Comment: I have in my python code a function where I have `ConfirmIntent` as `dialogAction's type` but I am not calling this function from anywhere in my code so its just sitting redundantly

Comment: For me, that was causing a problem as I was using it on intent's invocation. Not sure why you are facing this issue.

Comment: how did you resolved it? Did you just removed it? In my case I am guessing `Delegate` type in the DialogAction might be causing issue. Do you also have 2 or more intents in the same bot? When i have only 1 intent in the bot it executes fine but when I add another intent this error comes

Comment: I was getting this too. For me, I was defaulting an empty string into slots. The docs specify you must default null if the slot value is unknown (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html). When I did this, it worked.