# Lex chat bot error: Reached second execution of fulfillment lambda on the same utterance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I've read the [Lex Docs on Responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html).
I've searched and found:
- An unanswered [question on same error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424680/reached-second-execution-of-fulfillment-lambda-on-the-same-utterance)
- An unanswered [similar question but in Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448538/error-on-lex-bot-console-reached-second-execution-of-fulfillment-lambda-on-the)
- An unanswered [similar question in Amazon Dev Forum.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=257492)

So my question remains. What is causing / How to fix this error in Lex chat bot:

> An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response:
>   Reached second execution of fulfillment lambda on the same utterance

The error is only occurring when attempting to respond with Delegate. Here is my AWS lambda (node.js 6.10) code for the Delegate response:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        intentProcessor(event,
            (response) => {
                callback(null, response);
            });
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};

function intentProcessor(intentRequest, callback) {
     respond = delegate(sessionAttributes,intentRequest['currentIntent']['slots']);
     callback(respond);
}

function delegate(sessionAttributes, slots){
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: "Delegate",
            slots
        }
    };
}
```

I've confirmed that the response is returning as expected with the minimum requirements for Delegate per Docs, which are sessionAttributes and DialogAction: type and slots. The slots are returning null as expected.

Additional possibly relevant information:
- The intent has multiple utterances.
- The intent has multiple slots.
- None of the slots are required.

Any suggestions or information on what might cause this error is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you are calling `delegate()` in the `FulfillmentCodeHook`. When delegate is called it means that

> Lambda function directs Amazon Lex to choose the next course of action

Now, there are two actions in Lambda function, `DialogCodeHook` and `FulfillmentCodeHook`. If you are in DialogCodeHook, then `delegate` will call FulfillmentCodeHook. But if you are in FulfillmentCodeHook then it will throw an error.

However, if you are in FulfillmentCodeHook, and due to some reason you want to modify value of any `slot` then you can set value of that `slot` to **null** and then call the delegate passing new set of slots. This way, delegate will call DialogCodeHook again.

From AWS docs:

> If the value of the field is unknown, you must set it to null. You
>   will get a DependencyFailedException exception if your fufillment
>   function returns the Delegate dialog action without removing any
>   slots.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely pointed me in the right direction. I had my Lambda Function only used in the "Fulfillment" section and not in the  "Initialization and Validation" section which is used for `DialogCodeHook`. That solves it if the slots are required, but I don't think you can use `Delegate` for unrequired slots, so I had to use `ElicitSlot` for unrequired slots. Thank you!